# how to replace the "," between double-quote in VIM

Tags: vim

i have a CSV file,and the data is like this:

```
"asdd","12","good"
```

but some data are not regulate,like

```
"name1,name2","34","bad"
```

how to replace the ','  to another (eg '|' or '-' etc.) between double-quote?

ADD: the file size is almost to 40M.

Comment: i just make a example above,the date maybe like "name1,name2,name3...","44","bad" ,too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [csv plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830). It provides many possibilities to work with CSV files. In your case, you simply use `:NewDelimiter |` to make the `|` the new delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly then following command should solve the problem

```
:%s/\v([^"]),([^"])/\1-\2/g
```

It will replace all `,` that are not surrounded by `"` with `-`

Here it is assumed that all csv data are surrounded by `"`

Sample Input:

```
"name1,name2","34","bad"
"asdd","12","good"
"name1,name2,name3","34","bad"
```

Output:

```
"name1-name2","34","bad"
"asdd","12","good"
"name1-name2-name3","34","bad"
```

Comment: i just make a example above,the data maybe like "name1,name2,name3...","44","bad" ,too

Comment: @guanyue It will take care of all such cases. Although there dis an assumption that all csv data are surrounded by `"`

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
%s/[^"]\zs,\ze[^"]/-/g
```

if you want to handle(remove) spaces before and after the `,`, e.g:

```
"name1,   name2","34","bad"
"asdd","12","good"
"name1,  name2  ,name3","34","bad"
```

you can execute:

```
%s/[^"]\zs\s*,\s*\ze[^"]/-/g
```

it will change the above example into:

```
"name1-name2","34","bad"
"asdd","12","good"
"name1-name2-name3","34","bad"
```

Comment: Interesting! Avoided use of capturing but how? It seems `\z` does the trick. I tried to search but all I could get is `\z` is used for syntax folding. Can you please provide a reference or short description?

Comment: @jkshah You want `:h /\zs` or `:h /\ze`

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
:s/","/"|"/g
```

Will replace every "," in the document with a "|"

This will change:

```
"Hello","world","foo,bar"
```

to

```
"Hello"|"world"|"foo,bar"
```

Comment: but i want to save the double-quote,just replace the ',' in the double-quote,not in all document

Comment: This will replace the , that is surrounded by double quotes. It is changing the character you are  using as a delimiter and preserving the information in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** every `","` are regular them:

```
:%s/\(",\{-}"\)\|,/-\1/g
```

followed by

```
:%s/-"/"/g
```

Should work

Also:

```
:%s/\(\<\(",.\{-}"\>\)\@!\k\+\>\),/\1-/g
```